Почему обьекты проходят сквозь стены и пустоту, помеченные для AStarGrid как непроходимые?
Создал map.gd скрипт, который создает и размечает AStarGrid2D, перебирая все тайлы и помечая Void и Wall, как непроходимые (astar.set_point_solid(coords, true))
В goblin.gd и enemy_warrior.gd (просто 2 разных персонажа, код у них одинаков) обращаюсь к $'../Map'.astar.get_id_path(start, end), затем просто перемещаю персонажей на одну клетку.
Не могу понять почему обьекты игнорируют непроходимость. В рабочем варианте обьекты должны обходить препятствия. Залил на гитхаб упрощенный код, только с затронутыми проблемными участками.
Вот ссылка на репозиторий.
Вот код: map.gd
extends TileMapLayer

var astar = AStarGrid2D.new()

# Проблемный момент 1. Инициализация AStarGrid и отметка Wall и Void как непроходимые
func _ready() -> void:
    
    var tilemapSize = get_used_rect().end - get_used_rect().position
    var mapRect = Rect2i(-20, -10, 70, 70)
    
    var tileSize = tile_set.tile_size
    astar.region = mapRect
    astar.cell_size = tileSize
    astar.default_compute_heuristic = AStarGrid2D.HEURISTIC_MANHATTAN
    astar.default_estimate_heuristic = AStarGrid2D.HEURISTIC_MANHATTAN
    astar.diagonal_mode = AStarGrid2D.DIAGONAL_MODE_NEVER
    astar.update()
    
    for i in tilemapSize.x:
        for j in tilemapSize.y:
            var coords = Vector2i(i, j)
            var tileData = get_cell_tile_data(coords)
            if tileData and tileData.get_custom_data('Type') == 'Wall':
                astar.set_point_solid(coords, true)
            elif tileData and tileData.get_custom_data('Type') == 'Void':
                astar.set_point_solid(coords, true)


И код goblin.gd:
extends CharacterBody2D

@onready var tilemap = $"../Map"
var currentPath: Array[Vector2i]
var target_position: Vector2
var is_moving

# Проблемный момент 2. Запрос get_id_path и последующее перемещение обьекта по карте
func make_turn():
    var start = tilemap.local_to_map(position)
    var end = tilemap.local_to_map(get_enemy().position)
    currentPath = tilemap.astar.get_id_path(start, end)
    if currentPath.size() > 2:
        currentPath.pop_front()
        target_position = tilemap.map_to_local(currentPath[0])
        is_moving = true

func _physics_process(delta):
    if is_moving == true:
        if position.distance_to(target_position) > 1:
            position = position.move_toward(target_position, 100 * delta)
        else:
            is_moving = false
            $"../../Dungeon".turn_completed()


func get_enemy():
    var closest_enemy = null
    var shortest_distance = INF
    for enemy in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("adv"):
        if not is_instance_valid(enemy):
            continue
        var distance = position.distance_to(enemy.position)
        if distance < shortest_distance:
            shortest_distance = distance
            closest_enemy = enemy
    return closest_enemy


А также global.gd:
extends Node

var turn
var entities = {
    'monsters': [],
    'adv': []
}
# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready() -> void:
    turn = 'prepare'

и enemy_warrior.gd:
extends CharacterBody2D

@onready var tilemap = $"../Map"
var currentPath: Array[Vector2i]
var target_position: Vector2
var is_moving
signal turn_completed
    
func _ready():
    target_position = position

# Проблемный момент 2. Запрос get_id_path и последующее перемещение обьекта по карте
func make_turn():
    var start = tilemap.local_to_map(position)
    var end = tilemap.local_to_map(get_enemy().position)
    currentPath = tilemap.astar.get_id_path(start, end)
    if currentPath.size() > 2:
        currentPath.pop_front()
        target_position = tilemap.map_to_local(currentPath[0])
        is_moving = true

func _physics_process(delta):
    if is_moving == true:
        if position.distance_to(target_position) > 1:
            position = position.move_toward(target_position, 100 * delta)
        else:
            is_moving = false
            turn_completed.emit()


func get_enemy():
    var closest_enemy = null
    var shortest_distance = INF
    for enemy in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("monsters"):
        if not is_instance_valid(enemy):
            continue
        var distance = position.distance_to(enemy.position)
        if distance < shortest_distance:
            shortest_distance = distance
            closest_enemy = enemy
    return closest_enemy


К сожалению я не знаю как уместить код 3-х узлов в одном, чтобы всё это заработало, но окей, сейчас отредактирую. Желаемое поведение думаю и так понятно, чтобы обьекты не могли ходить через Void и Wall. С проблемой куда конкретнее я не знаю. Всё описал по максимуму, заново создал упрощенный код программы и залил на гит, тк сюда файлы нельзя. Ошибки консоль мне не выдала.
